# How to preserve generic type in async computation expression?

Tags: f#

Why is the generic type constrained to unit, and how can I write this in a way that myFunc gets properly typed as `unit -> Async<'t>`?

```
let myFunc (func: unit -> Async<'t>) = // myFunc: unit -> Async<unit>
    async {
        try
            do! Async.Sleep 500
            return! func() // 't constrained to unit here
        with _ex ->
            do! Async.Sleep 200
        
        failwith "failed"
    }
```

Edit: I was hoping this would make for a good minimal repro, but here's what I actually want to do:

```
let retryUntilTimeout (func: unit -> Async<'t>) timeout =
    async {
        let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        while sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < timeout do
            try
                return! func ()
            with _ex ->
                printfn "failed"
                do! Async.Sleep 200

        raise (TimeoutException())
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every expression must have a definite type, including a `try ... with` expression. Having a definite type, in this case, means that both the `try` and the `with` branches must have the same type.

But in your code, the `try` branch returns `'t`, while the `with` branch returns `unit`. But no matter: since `'t` can be anything, we can just unify it with `unit`, and now the whole `try ... with` expression returns `unit` as well. Problem solved!

To fix this, you need to have the `with` branch return a `'t` as well. How to do that, where to get a `'t`? I'm afraid I can't help you there, you must decide.

```
let myFunc (func: unit -> Async<'t>) = 
    async {
        try
            do! Async.Sleep 500
            return! func()
        with _ex ->
            do! Async.Sleep 200
            return someOtherValueOfT
        
        failwith "failed"
    }
```

---

But from the overall shape of the code, I *suspect* that what you really meant was to put the `failwith` under the `with` branch as well. Because `failwith` can have any type you want, this will make the compiler happy with keeping the type of the whole `try ... with` block as `'t`:

```
let myFunc (func: unit -> Async<'t>) =
    async {
        try
            do! Async.Sleep 500
            return! func()
        with _ex ->
            do! Async.Sleep 200   
            return failwith "failed"
    }
```

(note that there is now an extra `return` keyword inside `with` - that's because without a `return` the async block is assumed to have type `unit`, and we're back to the same problem)

---

Responding to your comments, it looks like what you're *actually* trying to do is an endless iteration, limited by a timeout, and you want to keep iterating as long as there is an error.

The problem with your code, however, is that it won't actually work the way you expect, even if you somehow return a value of `'t` from the `with` branch. This is because the `return!` keyword doesn't "interrupt execution" like it does in C# (formally known as "early return"), but merely runs the given `func()` and makes its value the result of the current block.

In fact, if you remove the `with` branch entirely, the problem will persist: the compiler will still insist on the type of `func()` being `unit`. This is because the call is inside a `while` loop, and the body of the `while` loop must not return a value, otherwise that value effectively gets thrown away, so there must be a mistake of some sort. But it's ok to throw away a `unit`, so the compiler allows it.

A good way to do what you're trying to do is via recursion:

```
let retryUntilTimeout (func: unit -> Async<'t>) timeout =
    let sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()

    let rec loop () = async { 
        if sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > timeout 
        then 
            return raise (TimeoutException())
        else
            try
                return! func ()
            with _ex ->
                printfn "failed"
                do! Async.Sleep 200
                return! loop ()
    }

    loop ()
```

Here, the function `loop` first checks the timeout and throws (note also the `return` keyword - that's to satisfy the type system), otherwise runs `func()`, but if that fails, waits a bit and calls itself recursively, thus continuing the process.

This general scheme (or stuff built on top of it) is how all iteration is modeled in functional programming. Forget about loops, they're not helpful.

Comment: Thanks for answering in detail. I'm afraid neither will do for my use case, which I failed to describe in the OP. I've added the function I'm actually trying to write; I'd appreciate if you could also give your advice on how to write it.

Comment: Updated the answer